# Can OGDF (a self-contained C++ library for graph algorithms) be integrated into Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, interoperability, c++

I would like to begin by congratulating IGraphM on the release of its current update (M 0.6.1). This package makes graph calculations on *Mathematica* much smoother.

The specifics are available at the following web address:

- https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM

As the author szhorvat says,

> The IGraph/M package provides a Wolfram Language interface to the
> popular igraph network analysis and graph theory library, as well as
> many other useful functions for working with graphs in Mathematica.

`igraph` is known to be a **C++** library. It offers numerous functions related to the calculation of graph parameters. However, its graph layout functions are currently limited.

I've seen that [ogdf](https://ogdf.uos.de/), (also a c++ library), has more advantages in the drawing and layout domains of network.

I have not had a positive experience with ogdf due to my lack of familiarity with c++ (though I plan to learn c++ in the future). Python has an interface of ogdf, but installing ogdf requires more than a single click (this requires a **local build of the ogdf** and it beat me). Below is an example of Python utilising odgf (https://pypi.org/project/ogdf-python/).

```
# uncomment if you didn't set this globally:
# %env OGDF_BUILD_DIR=~/ogdf/build-debug
from ogdf_python import ogdf, cppinclude
cppinclude("ogdf/basic/graph_generators/randomized.h")
cppinclude("ogdf/layered/SugiyamaLayout.h")

G = ogdf.Graph()
ogdf.setSeed(1)
ogdf.randomPlanarTriconnectedGraph(G, 20, 40)
GA = ogdf.GraphAttributes(G, ogdf.GraphAttributes.all)

for n in G.nodes:
    GA.label[n] = "N%s" % n.index()

SL = ogdf.SugiyamaLayout()
SL.call(GA)
ogdf.GraphIO.drawSVG(GA, "sugiyama-simple.svg")
GA
```

[image]

odgf is not only good at laying out graphs, but it also has many functions related to geometric graph theory. For example, it can calculate the crossing number of a given graph and  figure out whether or not it is [1-planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph).  So it would be very exciting if `ogdf` has an interface to `Mathematica` like igraph in the future.

Comment: Yes, of course it can be done, but it is a lot of work, and someone has to take the time. Specifically regarding graph drawing: One problem with integrating non-trivial layout algorithms into Mathematica is that there is no way to route edges. Mathematica's own built-in layout functions can set not only vertex coordinates, but also a specific path for each edge, as a list of point. This list of points is then passed to the `EdgeShapeFunction` to render the edge. However, this functionality cannot be access by users. I have requested it to be publicly exposed several times ...

Comment: ... years ago, but I never received any feedback about this from Wolfram. This is why IGraph/M does not expose igraph's Sugiyama layout.

Comment: BTW Mathematica does include the Sugiyama layout as LayeredDigraphEmbedding: `Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3}, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]`. Notice that this produces curved edges that avoid collisions with vertices. It is this type of layout that is impossible to set on a `Graph` expression manually. You can also contact Wolfram and request that they finally add this feature. If they suggest using a custom `EdgeShapeFunction`, tell them that this comes with severe drawbacks: we won't be able to customize other aspect of edge shapes!

Comment: The edge _route_ and the the edge _rendering_ should be separated. The former is not user-accessible, the latter can be done with `EdgeShapeFunction`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for telling me the technical difficulties involved. I need to know a lot more about c++ and mathematica before I can think about these details.

Comment: Fortunately, I can currently use the virtual platform provided by the author (ogdf-python).  I have been exploring for some time on how to install and use it locally.

Comment: @licheng I'm currently working on a pre-built version of the OGDF as python package, you could try running `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ ogdf-wheel==2022.2`. ogdf-python should pick up the binary automatically afterwards. More info on this will hopefully be available soon [here](https://github.com/N-Coder/ogdf-wheel). If you encounter any issues, feel free to report them there.

Comment: @NCode Thank you for your work!  I had a problem installing it (windows 10). Is it currently only supported on linux?

Comment: Yes, the prebuilt binary is Linux-only at the moment. There is currently [a bug](https://github.com/wlav/cppyy/issues/74) in the Python-C++ interface library I'm using, which prevents usage of ogdf-python on Windows as a whole. As soon as that bug is resolved, I'll push binaries for all OSes.